Run Nextjs from a read only folder, store cache data elsewhere?
I'm trying to run a nextjs website to an Azure Linux app service in Read-only mode.
It's working properly but nextjs tries to write to (web root)/.next folder (/home/site/wwwroot) to refresh the static props and pages.
How do I set the .next folder to be outside the project root? I checked the next.config.js file option 'dataDir' and set it to "/tmp" but the program actually looks for it inside the project folder not outside.
Is it possible to run nextjs from a read-only folder and have cache data stored elsewhere?

can you provide your github repo ?

Are you looking for this


When you deploy an application to Azure App Service, the contents of your project are placed under the wwwroot folder. This is the default behavior for Azure App Service.
If you want your application to be in Read-only mode, you can deploy your app to Azure Static Web App.

As you want to set the .next folder outside the project root, you can use a script deploy.sh to move files to your required location after the deployment.
I've added distDir:'/tmp/.next' in next.config.js to build and store the output files.
next.config.js:
/** @type  {import('next').NextConfig} */
const  nextConfig  = {
reactStrictMode:  true,
distDir:'/tmp/.next',
};
export  default  nextConfig;
export  default  nextConfig;

The script in deploy.sh creates a directory outside the wwwroot folder to store the .next build files.
My deploy .sh:
mkdir  -p  /home/nextjssample/tmp/.next
if [ -d  "/home/site/wwwroot/.next" ]; then
mv  /home/site/wwwroot/.next  /home/nextjssample/tmp/.next
fi

Execute deploy.sh in the Kudu console to move the .next folder from wwwroot to  /home/nextjssample/tmp/.next.

So, after running the scripts in deploy.sh, the .next folder is moved to /home/nextjssample/tmp/.next
bash deploy.sh 



